# How to know Vector3 Position in Unity Mono Game

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering

I want to get a gameObject.transform.position outside of a game written in Unity.

How do i find an offset of those values in winapi c++ code ?
I have DnSpy installed and it shows me this
[DnSpy screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAOZw.png)

I tried to install MelonLoader, but i encouraged an error while installing
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBcVQ.png)
[Error on 0.5.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0zZB.png)

Comment: C# has a moving garbage collector, which means the object will be constantly moving in memory ..... so even if you could get its position, it will only be valid for a few milliseconds.

Comment: don't know if what you want to do is possible or not but you can use [persistent data path](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) to store data that you want as a text file.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Unless you're trying to write a cheat, if it's your own project, you can maybe try a TCP connection between the Unity app that you built and the monitoring C or C++ app that you made. Other possibilities might be a plugin and/or C++/CLI.